# How to retrieve and set the parameters of LSTMCell?

Tags: lstm, tensorflow

I would like to retrive the parameters of BasicLSTMCell, and to initialize an object with given parameters with python.

I already looked to [Tensorflow Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/97f585d506cccc57dc98f234f4d5fcd824dd3c03/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell.py#L353) and [BasicLSTMCell guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/rnn_cell.html#BasicLSTMCell), but I'm not able to understand how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35013080/tensorflow-how-to-get-all-variables-from-rnn-cell-basiclstm-rnn-cell-multirnn)

```
cell = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(num_nodes)

with tf.variable_scope("LSTM") as vs:
# Execute the LSTM cell here in any way, for example:
for i in range(num_steps):
    output[i], state = cell(input_data[i], state)

# Retrieve just the LSTM variables.
lstm_variables = [v for v in tf.all_variables()
                if v.name.startswith(vs.name)]

# [..]
# Initialize the LSTM variables.
tf.initialize_variables(lstm_variables)
```